# intersection of one element of two nested lists?

Tags: python-3.x, intersection

Actually I have searched other questions about intersection of two nested lists, but I could not fix my problem, it's a little bit different. 
For example I have two lists

```
c1=[2,4,5] 
c2=[[2,23,43],[7,54,12],[4,97,52],[9,21,25],[5,34,23]]
```

I want to obtain the components of c2 which its first elements is same c1, it means I need to obtain:

```
c3=[[2,23,43],[4,97,52],[5,34,23]]
```

have you guys any idea about it !?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this list comprehension, which returns each element of `c2` if it has an intersection with `c1`:

```
>>> [i for i in c2 if set(c1).intersection(i)]

[[2, 23, 43], [4, 97, 52], [5, 34, 23]]
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for your super quickly reply :)

Comment: In your case, if c2=[97,4,52], this will be included yet the first number is not in c1. i believe you should do something like `[i for i in c2 if i[0] in c1]`

Comment: I misread the question, @Onyambu posted the correct solution to your problem :)